# How to divide multiple values within a column by a constant?

Tags: text-processing, awk

I am trying to divide the values in 2 columns by a certain constant. However, there are multiple values in each column that are separated by a colon. The file is very large (24 files, 2-3 GB each) For example, my file has the layout of :

```
1   18  N   112:0:0:0:0:0   126:0:0:0:0:0   19:0:0:0:0:0    20:0:0:0:0:0
1   19  N   0:0:114:0:0:0   0:0:136:0:0:0   0:0:18:0:0:0    0:0:19:0:0:0
1   20  N   0:112:0:0:0:7   0:125:0:0:0:20  0:16:0:0:0:3    0:13:0:0:0:5
```

I would hope for the output to look like this:

```
1   18  N   56:0:0:0:0:0    63:0:0:0:0:0    19:0:0:0:0:0    20:0:0:0:0:0
1   19  N   0:0:57:0:0:0    0:0:68:0:0:0    0:0:18:0:0:0    0:0:19:0:0:0
1   20  N   0:56:0:0:0:3.5  0:62.5:0:0:0:10 0:16:0:0:0:3    0:13:0:0:0:5
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not exactly straightforward, since (riffing on @berndbausch's idea of using `split`), awk doesn't have a built-in way of flattening arrays back into strings. We need to use printf, and a consequence of this is that awk forgets how to align the output nicely.

But this does work:

```
#! /usr/bin/gawk -f

function print_div2(arr) {
    split(arr, a, ":")
    printf(" %d", a[1]/2)
    delete a[1]
    for(i in a) printf(":%d", a[i]/2)
}

{
    ORS=""
    print $1, $2, $3 " "
    print_div2($4)
    print " "
    print_div2($5)
    print " "
    ORS="\n"
    print $6, $7
}
```

Commentary: ORS is used to suppress any newline from `print` until we are finished processing each record. And we give the fields 4 and 5 to the print_div2 function, which splits the records into an array and prints half of each entry.

Put it in a file and mark it executable. Example usage:

```
$ ./process.awk data.txt
1 18 N  56:0:0:0:0:0  63:0:0:0:0:0 19:0:0:0:0:0 20:0:0:0:0:0
1 19 N  0:0:57:0:0:0  0:0:68:0:0:0 0:0:18:0:0:0 0:0:19:0:0:0
1 20 N  0:56:0:0:0:3  0:62:0:0:0:10 0:16:0:0:0:3 0:13:0:0:0:5
```

Neat column alignment can be restored using `column`:

```
$ ./process.awk data.txt | column -t
1  18  N  56:0:0:0:0:0  63:0:0:0:0:0   19:0:0:0:0:0  20:0:0:0:0:0
1  19  N  0:0:57:0:0:0  0:0:68:0:0:0   0:0:18:0:0:0  0:0:19:0:0:0
1  20  N  0:56:0:0:0:3  0:62:0:0:0:10  0:16:0:0:0:3  0:13:0:0:0:5
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '
    function dyd(col, n){
        split(col, t, ":");
        sep=":";
        return t[1]/n sep t[2]/n sep t[3]/n sep t[4]/n sep t[5]/n sep t[6]/n;
    };
{ $4=dyd($4, 2); $5=dyd($5, 2); }1' infile |column -t
```